# Java Swing dialog buttons and icons

Tags: java, swing, button, dialog, icons

I am currently learning Java and i'm on a lesson that teaches Dialog boxes.
Currently I know how to change the Icon option but how about adding some buttons?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text to display", "Title", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

^ shows the warning error as it should and the ok button but i'd like to also have a cancel button

Unfortunately

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text to display", "Title", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

returns an error. Basically since i'm a beginner I have no ideea where to put the ok_cancel_option part. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, 
                              "message", 
                              "title", 
                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

`showMessageDialog()` is used for alerts if you want a confimation dialog you have to use `showConfirmDialog()` as shown above

PS: forgot to mention `showConfirmDialog()` returns a result

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, 
                                           "message", 
                                           "title", 
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
     //stuff to do if yes
}
if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
     //stuff to do if no
}
```

Comment: Multumesc mult pentru raspuns!

Comment: Cu placere, vezi completarea cum sa primesti raspunsul